# Accessing struct field gives address rather than value

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I have some embedded c code which uses void pointers and pointer arithmetic to implement a general-purpose linked list. I am using the list to store structures of type `stopwatch_t`. The problem I am having is that when I pull items out of the list and cast them from `void` pointers to `stopwatch_t` pointers, they are not behaving as expected. When I try to access the fields of the struct I am getting addresses rather than values. See the last comment in the code below for more details.

Complete code for the linked list;

h file

```
typedef uint16_t list_index_t;

typedef struct
{
    void *              p_values;
    uint16_t *      p_links;
    uint16_t            el_size;
    uint16_t            list_size;
    list_index_t    first;
    list_index_t    last;
    bool                    empty;
} list_t;

typedef struct 
{   
    list_t * p_list;
    bool before_first;  
    list_index_t current;
} list_enumerator_t;


#define LIST_INIT(P_LIST, EL_SIZE, LIST_SIZE)                                                      \
        do                                                                                                                                                                                       \
        {                                                                                                                                                                                            \
                static uint8_t values[LIST_SIZE*EL_SIZE];                                                                                                  \
              static uint16_t links[LIST_SIZE];                                                                                                              \
              static list_t list;                                                                               \
                uint32_t err = list_init(&list, values, links, EL_SIZE, LIST_SIZE);                                      \
                APP_ERROR_CHECK(err);                                                                                                                                          \
                (*P_LIST) = &list;                                                                         \
        } while (0);
```

c file

```
#include <string.h>
#include "compiler_abstraction.h"
#include "list.h"

static __INLINE list_index_t get_successor(list_t * p_list, list_index_t current);
static __INLINE void set_successor(list_t * p_list, list_index_t index, list_index_t successor_index);
static __INLINE list_index_t get_predecessor(list_t * p_list, list_index_t target);
static __INLINE void * get_value(list_t * p_list, list_index_t index);

uint32_t list_init( list_t *    p_list, 
                                        void * p_values, 
                                        uint16_t * p_links, 
                                        uint16_t    el_size, 
                                        uint16_t    list_size)
{
    p_list->p_values = p_values;
    p_list->p_links = p_links;
    p_list->el_size = el_size;
    p_list->list_size = list_size;
    p_list->first = 0;
    p_list->last = 0;
    p_list->empty = true;

    // link all nodes
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < (list_size - 1); i++)
    {
        p_links[i] = i+1;
    }
    p_links[list_size-1] = 0;

    return NRF_SUCCESS;
}

bool list_empty(list_t * p_list)
{
    return (p_list->empty);
}

bool list_full(list_t * p_list)
{
    list_index_t first = p_list->first;
    list_index_t last = p_list->last;
    list_index_t after_last = get_successor(p_list, last);
    return (first == after_last);
}

// Precondition: !list_full(p_list)
list_index_t list_insert(list_t * p_list, void * p_value)
{
    // determine where new value will go
    list_index_t new_index = 
        p_list->empty ? 
            p_list->last : 
            get_successor(p_list, p_list->last);

    // copy value into list
    void * p_new_value = get_value(p_list, new_index);
    memcpy(p_new_value, p_value, p_list->el_size);

    // update links
    p_list->last = new_index;

    p_list->empty = false;

    return new_index;
}

void * list_lookup(list_t * p_list, list_index_t index)
{
    return get_value(p_list, index);
}

// Precondition: !list_empty(p_list)
void list_delete(list_t * p_list, list_index_t del)
{
    // update empty status
    // note: the only valid way to get an empty list is to delete an
    //       item from a list with only one item.
    p_list->empty = p_list->first == p_list->last;

    // delete items from beginning of list
    if (p_list->first == del)
    {
        p_list->first = get_successor(p_list, del); 
    }

    // delete item from end of list
    else if (p_list->last == del)
    {
        p_list->last = get_predecessor(p_list, del);
    }

    // delete item from middle of list
    else
    {
        // remove node from chain
        list_index_t before_del = get_predecessor(p_list, del);
        list_index_t after_del = get_successor(p_list, del);
        set_successor(p_list, before_del, after_del);

        // insert node back into chain after last
        list_index_t after_last = get_successor(p_list, p_list->last);
        set_successor(p_list, del, after_last);
        set_successor(p_list, p_list->last, del);       
    }
}

static __INLINE list_index_t get_predecessor(list_t * p_list, list_index_t target)
{
    // start at first populated index
    list_index_t x = p_list->first;
    list_index_t y = get_successor(p_list, x);
    while (y != target)
    {
        x = y;
        y = get_successor(p_list, y);
    }
    return x;
}

static __INLINE list_index_t get_successor(list_t * p_list, list_index_t current)
{
    return (p_list->p_links)[current];
}

static __INLINE void set_successor(list_t * p_list, list_index_t index, list_index_t successor_index)
{
    (p_list->p_links)[index] = successor_index;
}

static __INLINE void * get_value(list_t * p_list, list_index_t index)
{
    return (void *)
        ((uint32_t)(p_list->p_values) + (index * p_list->el_size));
}

list_enumerator_t list_enumerate(list_t * p_list)
{
    list_enumerator_t enumerator;
    enumerator.before_first = true;
    enumerator.p_list = p_list;
    return enumerator;
}

bool enumerator_move_next(list_enumerator_t * p_enumerator)
{
    bool result;
    list_t * p_list = p_enumerator->p_list;

    if (p_enumerator->before_first)
    {
        p_enumerator->current = p_list->first;
        p_enumerator->before_first = false;
        result = !list_empty(p_list);
    }
    else if (p_enumerator->current == p_list->last)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    else
    {
        p_enumerator->current = get_successor(p_list, p_enumerator->current);
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}

void * enumerator_current(list_enumerator_t * p_enumerator)
{
    list_t * p_list = p_enumerator->p_list;
    list_index_t index = p_enumerator->current;
    return get_value(p_list, index);
}
```

Relevant parts of the stopwatch;

```
static list_t * p_slots;

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t start;
    uint32_t rollovers;
} stopwatch_t;

uint32_t stopwatch_init(void)
{
    stopwatch_t stopwatch;
    LIST_INIT(&p_slots, sizeof stopwatch, MAX_STOPWATCHES);
    ...
    return OK;
}

stopwatch_id_t stopwatch_start(void)
{
    stopwatch_t stopwatch;
    stopwatch.start = timer1_now();
    stopwatch.rollovers = 0;
    ...
    stopwatch_id_t id = list_insert(p_slots, (void *)(&stopwatch));
    ...
    return id;
}

uint64_t stopwatch_get_elapsed_time(stopwatch_id_t id)
{
    ...
    stopwatch_t * p_stopwatch = list_lookup(p_slots, (list_index_t)id);
    uint16_t start_ticks = (p_stopwatch->start);
    uint32_t rollovers = (p_stopwatch->rollovers);
    /* PROBLEM: variables 'start_ticks' & 'rollovers' now contain the addresses */
    /*          of the values I want, rather than the values themselves.        */
    ...
}
```

This is the first time I've used void pointers. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: How do you initialize the list? How do you know, that `start` and `rollovers` are addresses? Please provide more information or an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your `list_t` doesn't look like a linked list.  It looks like a dynamically-allocated array of fixed-size elements.

Comment: recommend you to have a look how linked list is implemented in linux kernel. that's very concise. and you said this is a linked list implementation, why i couldn't see any `next` type of pointers?

Comment: @zoska I am running the code in the debugger. The debugger allows me to see both the addresses of my variables, and their values. Strangely enough, I evaluate the expressions in the watch window they work fine. But running the code gives a different result.

Comment: That looks like an array, not a linked list. In a linked list you have pointers from each element to the next. Did you remember to set `p_list->el_size` to `sizeof stopwatch` (and to allocate memory for `p_values`)?

Comment: @knick what do you mean by "running the code gives a different result?"

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I've only shown the code that I thought/hoped was relevant. I've omitted the next pointers because I wanted to keep it concise

Comment: @zoska I mean the values that are actually in variables `start_ticks` and `rollovers` are not the same values the values I get when I evaluate the expressions `p_stopwatch->start` and `p_stopwatch->rollovers` in the watch window. Evaluating in the watch window gives the expected result. Whereas the variables contain the addresses.

Comment: @knick you are confusing people now. maybe you can now add it to make it complete.

Comment: As @HuStmpHrrr said: give a minimal, *complete* example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: and your `list_lookup` has a serious problem. you don't do pointer arithmetic like that. and what is `list_index_t`?

Comment: it's absolutely not a linked list.

Comment: I still don't see how `p_list` pointer is initialized.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Why is it not a linked list? Keep in mind that this is an embedded application. I am not doing dynamic memory allocation. Everything is statically allocated.

Comment: @zoska see stopwatch_init(void)

Comment: @knick because you have no link. maybe you can have a read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list. btw, your macro `LIST_INIT` may have a chance to crash your code and wipe it into dust.

Comment: @HuStmpHrr you mentioned there is a problem with list_lookup and LIST_INIT. I would be interested to hear what they are...

Comment: in `LIST_INIT`, the problem is the static fields. if you have a section gets run for multiple times, exactly the same fields will be used. in `list_lookup`, you can't cast pointer to integer or reverse. it's not standardized and not supposed to be supported. pointer supports arithmetic itself, even `void *` supports arithmetic. you should directly operate on it.

Comment: `LIST_INIT(P_LIST, EL_SIZE, LIST_SIZE)     ` is missing backslashes and has a semicolon too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was nothing to do with the use of pointers or the pointer arithmetic. As it turns out, there was an error in return expression of function `stopwatch_get_elapsed_time(..)`. This error meant that the variables `start_ticks` and `rollovers` were not being used. Presumably the compiler has realised that the variables aren't being used and optimized them away.
This explains why the variables were showing strange values when watched in the debugger.